# How can I print results from lists in python?

Tags: python

I searched about here on stackoverflow but did not succeed when trying to print the results in question.

Here is the code:

```
import math


class KNNRegressao:

    def __init__(self, x, y, k=3):
        self.n_amostras = len(x)
        self.n_attrs = len(x[0])
        self.x, self.y, self.k = x, y, k

    def predict(self, amostra):
        d = {}
        for i in range(self.n_amostras):
            soma = 0
            for j in range(self.n_attrs):
                soma += math.pow(amostra[j] - self.x[i][j], 2)
            d[i] = math.sqrt(soma)
        k_vizinhos = sorted(d, key=d.get)[:self.k]
        soma = sum([self.y[indice] for indice in k_vizinhos])
        return soma / self.k


if __name__ == "main":
    entradas = [[2, 50], [4, 90], [1, 38], [5, 105], [2, 48], [6, 120], [3, 65], [4, 80], [5, 100], [3, 60]]
    saidas = [250, 490, 138, 505, 248, 612, 365, 480, 500, 360]
    knn = KNNRegressao(entradas, saidas, 3)
    resultado = []
    for entrada in entradas:
        resultado.append(knn.predict(entrada))
        print("Esperado: [%d]" % saidas)
        print("Predict: [%d]" % resultado)
```

I'm fairly new to python. I would like to know how I can print this list of results, I tried in several ways, but I could not. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `print(resultado)` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried...

Comment: OK, I see your problem:  `if __name__ == "__main__"`  - you missed out the underscores.

Comment: The `print("Esperado: [%d]" % saidas)` statements will fail, you can't format a list in that way.

Comment: You could use `print("Esperado: [%s]" % str(saidas))`, but there's not much point, you might as well:  `print("Esperado:", saidas)`

Comment: No problem, we all had to start somewhere.

Comment: Put it in the answer, please. I'll mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted the underscores:

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
```

so it never entered the `if`.

The `print("Esperado: [%d]" % saidas)` statements will fail, you can't format a list in that way. You could use `print("Esperado: [%s]" % str(saidas))`, but there's not much point, you might as well: `print("Esperado:", saidas)`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     entradas = [[2, 50], [4, 90], [1, 38], [5, 105], [2, 48], [6, 120], [3, 65], [4, 80], [5, 100], [3, 60]]
     saidas = [250, 490, 138, 505, 248, 612, 365, 480, 500, 360]
     knn = KNNRegressao(entradas, saidas, 3)
     resultado = []
     for entrada in entradas:
         resultado.append(knn.predict(entrada))
         print("Esperado:", saidas)
         print("Predict:" resultado)
```